# Flutter Web scrollwheel scrolls in slow steps on Firefox

Tags: flutter, web, firefox, mousewheel

Websites that are programmed with Flutter Web seem to have an issue when scrolling with the scrollwheel on the browser Firefox. Scrolling up and down with the scrollwheel does very small steps which gives a bad user experience. I tested this issue on alot of browser it only appears on Firefox. I also tested it on a bunch of different websites they all have the same problem. My website is https://alikortak.de if you want to try it yourself. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Ali Kartak? Did you solve the problem? Your website seems ok no firefox now....

Comment: @MoacirSchmidt Yes I used the package, that was suggested in the answer: https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_scroll_web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_scroll_web package and if you want a draggable scrollbar you can use the Cupertino Scrollbar.